# How to set double precision for elements of an array in Fortran 90

Tags: arrays, fortran, double, precision, gfortran

I am not very familiar with Fortran code and want to compare it to some C code. I have the following definition for an array for which I want to have double precision (as I want to compare numbers between the Fortran and C code with double precision).

```
INTEGER :: n = 3
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(n, 1) :: grid
```

Later I have

```
grid(1,1) = -2.85697001387280    
grid(2,1) = -1.35562617997427   
grid(3,1) =  0.00000000000000
```

Running the code through the debugger, To my surprise, debugger gives

```
grid = [-2.8569700717926025, -1.3556262254714966, 0]
```

which is only correct to single precision. I have also tried REAL*8, REAL(8) instead of DOUBLE PRECISION. I found it all the more surprising as the following code

```
INTEGER :: n = 3
REAL(8) :: mina = 0.5, maxa = 5.0 
REAL(8) :: lmina, step
REAL(8), DIMENSION(n,1) :: a

lmina = log(mina)
lmaxa = log(maxa)
step = (lmaxa - lmina) / (n - 1)
DO i=1,n
   a(i,1)=lmina+(i-1.0)*step
END DO
```

does create scalars and the array a that are accurate to double precision and exactly equal to the numbers of the C code. Why is this different in case of the hard-coded elements and how to fix it.

FYI, I compile the debug version as follows:

```
gfortran -g -o myfile myfile.f90
```

Comment: You need type kind parameter specification for all your double precision constants in Fortran, otherwise they will all lose precision down to default kind which is single precision, most likely.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? It is not clear to me how a and grid differ in their definition, but a seems to have double precision whereas a has not.

Comment: I have not worked with FORTRAN in quite some time, but a brief web search suggests a double-precision literal is indicated by using an exponent with `D`, as in `3.1D0`, or with a suffix such as `_8` or `_dp`, as in `3.1_8` or `3.1_dp`. [The latter may require additional statements.](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/973)

Comment: (@Scientist) the values you put in a are computed, not constants. For _constants_ you must write e.g. `-2.85697001387280_8` where 8 is the kind assigned by gfortran to dp aka REAL*8, or `-2.85697001387280_somename` where `somename` is a parameter set to 8, or the (simpler) traditional form `-2.85697001387280d0`. (Note C and Java are the reverse: 1.234 is double precision and you must specify 1.234f if you want to force single precision which people rarely do.)

Comment: Eric and Dave,,thanks a lot.! This sorts it. Due to the reverse default in C I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran is like C in that numeric literals have a default data type, and no attempt is made to infer the type from the left-hand side of an assignment.  Fortran is *not* like C in that the default for floating point literals is single precision (`REAL` in F77 and earlier, `REAL` with default `KIND` in F90 and later).  This must be overridden to get a double precision constant (`DOUBLE PRECISION` or in F90 and later `REAL` with specific non-default `KIND`).  Compare with C where you must override the default to get a single precision (`float`) constant.

In the code that you subsequently cited:

```
REAL(8) :: mina = 0.5, maxa = 5.0 
REAL(8) :: lmina, lmaxa, step
REAL(8), DIMENSION(n,1) :: a

lmina = log(mina)
lmaxa = log(maxa)
step = (lmaxa - lmina) / (n - 1)
DO i=1,n
   a(i,1)=lmina+(i-1.0)*step
END DO
```

Here it is unsurprising that the values end up being double precision without rounding.

1. `mina` and `maxa` are double precision (using the implementation-specific `KIND` value of 8, also see the other answer for the risks of working this way).  They are initialized from single precision literals, but both are exactly representable in binary floating point and thus there is no rounding.
2. `lmina` and `lmaxa` are double precision and calculated using a double precision `LOG` function.
3. `step` is double precision and calculated from double precision and integer values.
4. The value computed in the loop is from double precision variables (`lmina` and `step`) and a single precision literal `1.0` which is exactly representable and thus not rounded (and gets promoted to double precision in the computation).

You can get a double precision constant by using `D` instead of `E` in scientific notation or by appending an underscore followed by the appropriate `KIND` parameter (which may be either a numeric literal or an integer `PARAMETER` declared elsewhere).  A common idiom for doing this is to have a `MODULE` which is `USE`d to define a common numeric `KIND` type to use throughout; an example of this style is given in the other answer.

Comment: I'm possibly living in the past but don't you need `dlog` to force the double precision version?

Comment: @cup as of F90, `LOG` is a generic interface and will pick the correct version according to its argument (in this case, the argument is double precision so the double precision overload will be selected).  `DLOG` would be the `DOUBLE PRECISION` version if called specifically.  `ALOG` is the single-precision version.

Answer (score 2):

@Mike The (or a) right way of assigning kind type parameter is something like the following,

```
use iso_fortran_env, only: IK => int32, RK => real64
integer(IK), parameter :: n = 3_IK
real(RK) :: grid(n, 1)
grid = [-2.8569700717926025_RK, -1.3556262254714966_RK, 0._RK]
```

Don't ever use `REAL*8`, `REAL(8)`, or `0._8`. These are all non-portable (and the first is not even part of the standard) and can crash your code or yield extremely hard-to-debug segmentation faults when linking with external libraries compiled with different settings. `_8` is also hard to change across a codebase if used frequently everywhere. Instead, define a kind-agnostic label for the value like `IK` and `RK` in the above and use them everywhere. Without using kind designators, the values are converted to the default kind precision on the right-hand side and only then assigned to the left-hand side.
Note that `real64` does not guarantee a double precision. It only guarantees a container of 64bits for the real values. With this generic labeling, you can change the precision (or container) of all real values in your code by changing `real64` to other possibilities like `real32` or `real128` or any values in the vector `real_kinds` from the e`iso_fortran_env` intrinsic module. If you want a guarantee of double precision (minimum 15 digits) at any time with any compiler, you may want to use the following line instead of `real64` from the `iso_fortran_env` module,

```
use iso_fortran_env, only: IK => int32
integer, parameter :: RK = selected_real_kind(p = 15, r  = 308)
integer(IK), parameter :: n = 3_IK
real(RK) :: grid(n, 1)
grid = [-2.8569700717926025_RK, -1.3556262254714966_RK, 0._RK]
```

Consult a Fortran [reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fREAL_005fKIND.html) for details of `selected_real_kind()` intrinsic. In most cases, at least certainly with GNU and Intel compilers, the use of `selected_real_kind` is overkill, and `iso_fortran_env` offers a nice, readable, satisfactory result.

If you want precisely the same precision as you have with `double` in your C companion processor, then use `c_double` from `iso_c_binding` intrinsic module,

```
use iso_c_binding, only:  RK => c_double ! or c_float, or c_long_double
```

Comment: Note `Real(8)` and `0.0_8` are standard fortran, but not portable. But yes the other one which I shall not type is a nonstandard abomination

Comment: Although non standard, `real*8` has been for a long time a widely implemented extension that has the same meaning in all major compilers. This 'abomination' was actually an elegant solution when programming for different architectures with different default real sizes.

Comment: @PierU I am ancient so am unfortunately aware of that :) I still stand by what I say, since F90 compilers became widely available it is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Unnecessary, I can agree, but still not an "abomination". And actually better than using `real(8)` (the latter is standard, but is a diversion of the kind system).

Comment: Thanks @IanBush. I made a correction to the wording.